# Powershell: count properties SIZE block

Tags: powershell, amazon-rds, remote-desktop

I created following PowerShell line:

```
$size = (Get-RDSessionCollection -ConnectionBroker $CB |  select Collectionname, Size |ft)
```

as results I got:

> CollectionName Size
>
> ---
>
> Collection1     4 
> Collection2     29 
> Collection3     7

How may I count the size property (in this case 4+29+7=40).
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the Size you can do:

```
$size = (Get-RDSessionCollection -ConnectionBroker $CB |  measure-object -property size -sum).sum
```